# CRUD delete - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hey im making a small library project for practice, i have a table full of books loaded from my database, now i have created a delete button for each book, and i want to be able to press that to delete the book on the row.

It looks like this

[image]

Ive created the facade method both backend (in java) and in react/JS

```
function deleteBook(id){
  const options = makeOptions("DELETE")
  return fetch(SERVER_URL + "/api/boooks/" + id, options)
  .then(handleHttpErrors)
  .catch((err) => {
    if (err.status) {
      err.fullError.then((e) => console.log(e.message));
    } else {
      console.log("Network error");
    }
  });
}
```

Then ive created a delete method (which of course doesnt work) because i dont know how to get hold of the ID of the given book on the row, so it knows which one to delete.

```
  const deleteBook = (evt) => {
    apiFacade.deleteBook(evt.target.value)
  };
```

The table looks like this:

```
                    <tr key={m.isbn}>
                      <td>{m.isbn}</td>
                      <td>{m.title}</td>
                      <td>{m.author}</td>
                      <td>{m.publisher}</td>
                      <td>{m.publishYear}</td>
                      <td>
                        <button type="submit" onClick={deleteBook} className="btn btn-danger"><FaTrash /></button>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary"><FaPencilAlt /></button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
```

Can anyone help me?

EDIT: It works in postman on the server to delete by ID, just need to get it to work on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to "hold" the id. If the id is available in `m` object (if not, just make it), then you can simply do something like this:

```
<button type="submit" onClick={() => deleteBook(m.id)} className="btn btn-danger"><FaTrash /></button>

const deleteBook = (id) => {
    apiFacade.deleteBook(id)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your books collection is placed in `books` array. In render method or function component of some container you will have

```
return (
   <table>
      {tableRows}
   </table>
);
```

where `tableRows` is:

```
const tableRows = books.map(book => {
     const delete = () => {
        //yourDeleteMethod(book.id);
     };

     return (
        <tr key={book.isbn}>
          <td>{book.isbn}</td>
          <td>{book.title}</td>
          <td>{book.author}</td>
          <td>{book.publisher}</td>
          <td>{book.publishYear}</td>
          <td>
            <button type="submit" 
               onClick={delete} 
               className="btn btn-danger">
              <FaTrash />
            </button>
          </td>
          <td>
           <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary"><FaPencilAlt /> 
           </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
     )
})
```